# About Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am researching best practices for working with layouts in Android projects.

In the Android documentation says that from Android 3.2 to create qualifiers type -mdpi -hdpi etc is obsolete and that the best way is to create specific folders for each screen as sw600dp and etc. Also talks to create different layouts for each case, but how are the dimensions and images in this approach?

I create separate layouts for each case with fixed dimensions in the layout itself? How is that?

Images continue in folders like "dawable-mdpi"?

I spent some time studying the documentation but doubt continues ..
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct me if I am wrong.**

Before Android 3.0 drawable were placed in folders depending on the screen size. For supporting larger devices, putting drawable according to screen density was introduced. With this drawable were chosen depending on the pixel density of the screen and not just the size of the screen.
You can read about it in "How to Support Multiple Screens" section of this page https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

So I think using small, normal, large, and xlarge is depreciated and we now use ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), xhdpi extra-high), xxhdpi (extra-extra-high), and xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high)
And sw600dp, sw720dp etc are for devices with screen dimension at least 600dp, 720dp etc. You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

You'll find answers to all your question in the documentation you spent some time studying. Go through it again, and I am sure things will be a lot more clear to you.